# Meteor unwatch folder

Tags: reactjs, meteor, watch

I am trying to make a folder to be not watched. Is there a way to make one of the folders not watched in Meteor? I don't want my project to reload if I change a content in that folder.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly. Meteor assumes that if the folder content changes, it also needs to reload/restart the server, because the business logic of the application might have changed. Therefore it reloads these files and restarts the server

However, you might be able to "abuse" the **tests/** directory or any of the directories/files mentioned below for that purpose. As explained in the [Meteor guide on Application Structure](https://guide.meteor.com/structure.html), paragraph "Special directories":

> Any directory named tests/ is not loaded anywhere. Use this for any test code you want to run using a test runner outside of Meteor’s built-in test tools.
>
> The following directories are also not loaded as part of your app code:
>
> - Files/directories whose names start with a dot, like .meteor and .git
> - packages/: Used for local packages
> - cordova-build-override/: Used for advanced mobile build customizations
> - programs: For legacy reasons

So the reasonable choice would be to create a dot directory, e.g. `.myStuff`, and place anything that you might need to update but do not want to trigger a server restart there.

Comment: tests or packages folders still make my app to reload.

Answer (score 0):

Just build your app in a package so you can decide which files you want to make available or not :)

Comment: How do I build it in a package? I want to save some user images without making my app to reload

Comment: Would you like your app to upload user images ? If so then consider saving them on amazon s3. check this package https://github.com/VeliovGroup/Meteor-Files